# Centering div using bootstrap and css with html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to web designing and Im having problems with some bootstrap and css styling. I'm making a profile page and I have a profile picture and a name in a div surrounded by a border. The problem is, it's not centered in the middle of the page and I've been looking all over the place for a solution to this problem. This is what my html code looks like,

```
<div ng-controller = "profileController">
    <!-- profile pic -->
    <div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="profile">
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="center-block">
                                            <div class="profilePic">
                                                    <img ng-src="{{profilePic()}}" class="img-responsive">
                                                    <!-- name field -->
                                                    <label class="caption">
                                                            <h4>{{users.Name}}</h4>
                                                    </label>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="span1">
                                            <!-- role field -->
                                                    <p class="text-left">Role: </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="span1">
                                                    <p class="text-left">{{userid}}</p>
                                                    <p class="text-left">{{getRole()}}</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Im trying to use bootstrap as much as possible so I don't have a css file for this but it's fine if I have to use css to fix this problem. Stackoverflow isn't letting me post a screenshot but as of now, the div is placed to the far left and I need it to be centered.

Comment: Could you include an screencapture?

Comment: sorry but I think I am missing the boostrap part in your html.. reread the examples in boostrap, and switch to version3 if you haven't

Comment: @vico what do you mean switch to version 3? Stack overflow isn't letting me post a screenshot but as of now, the div is placed to the far left of the page and i need it to be in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using center-block, try using text-center on the profilePic div.

```
<div class="profilePic text-center">
```

**EDIT:**

Ah, yes, the img-responsive class is setting display to block. Try adding center-block to the img tag instead.

```
<img ng-src="{{profilePic()}}" class="img-responsive center-block">
```

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work. Intuitionally, I would think you I would need to do something with "<div ng-controller = "profileController">" because it's the outmost div but I'm probably wrong

Comment: I just tried it and sadly it still doesn't work. I'm going to read up on some tutorials for bootstrap and html and start over, the code doesn't look right but thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't help. I did test it on my end and it worked for me, but I stripped out all of the angular stuff and replaced with with standard attributes because I don't use Angular. :/